# Grafana: Unable to find dependent node 'A'

Tags: alert, grafana

While testing an alert, I got the following error message (failed to execute conditions: unable to find dependent node 'A'):

[image: Error message]

Here is the config template I am using:

```
    - title: Title
      condition: E
      data:
      - refID: A
        model:
          query: |-
            base = from(bucket: "...")
            ...
      - refID: B
    ...
      - refID: C
        ...
      - refId: D
        ...
      - refId: E
        datasourceUid: "-100"
        model:
          type: math
          expression: "$$B < 1"
```

I am using Grafana 9.1.0. What is a node according to Grafana? Does the error comes from the first query (`refID = A`) or the combinations of queries?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, for those having the same: I mixed `refID` and `refId`, the later one being the right syntax.